# Write file using mmap

Tags: c, linux, paging, mmap

I am creating a file with open using O_CREAT and then using ftruncate I set the size of the file. Now I mmap the file with MAP_SHARED and start writing the file. I wanted to understand how is the file written back to disk.

Very specifically my question is: Is this going to be zero copy, that is the page in buffer cache will be mapped directly in the process address space, in which case the page daemon will flush the page back to disk when it is scheduled. If not then there will be a page in the page cache and another page in the buffer cache. If this is the scenario at what granularity will the data be copied from the page in  page cache to page in buffer cache?

If there is some more insight you wish to give, it will be more than welcome :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since Linux has a unified buffer cache, yes this is zero copy. Most modern OSes have a unified buffer cache now.